# Compiling kernel version >= 2.6.34 on CentOS 5: RAID set "ddf1_foo" was not activated?

Tags: centos, centos5, kernel, kernel-panic, fakeraid

I want to [mount a Ceph FS](http://ceph.com/docs/master/cephfs/fuse/) on some CentOS 5 servers. Since the `ceph-fuse` failed with below errors:

```
# ceph-fuse --no-fuse-big-writes -m 192.168.2.15:6789 /mnt/ceph/
ceph-fuse[7528]: starting ceph client
ceph-fuse[7528]: starting fuse
fuse: unknown option `atomic_o_trunc'
2013-04-04 13:51:21.128506 2b82d6e9e8f0 -1 fuse_lowlevel_new failed
ceph-fuse[7528]: fuse finished with error 33
ceph-fuse[7526]: mount failed: (33) Numerical argument out of domain
```

Google pointed to [this](http://tracker.ceph.com/issues/4286) but CentOS 5.x shipped with kernel 2.6.18, I'm going to compile a newer kernel that supports Ceph.

- My first attempt is with [kernel-lt](http://elrepo.org/tiki/kernel-lt) 3.0.71 from the [ELRepo](http://elrepo.org/tiki/tiki-index.php)
- The second one is [2.6.34.14](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/longterm/v2.6.34/linux-2.6.34.14.tar.xz) from the kernel.org

The `.config` was copied from the running kernel with 2 additional settings:

```
CONFIG_SYSFS_DEPRECATED_V2=y
CONFIG_CEPH_FS=m
```

But both of them give me the following error:

[image]

The first warning can be got rid of by editing the init script after extracting the kernel image and removing 2 lines:

```
echo "Loading dm-region-hash.ko module"
insmod /lib/dm-region-hash.ko
```

http://funky-dennis.livejournal.com/3290.html

How about the second error:

```
device-mapper: table: 253:0: mirror: Error creating mirror dirty log
RAID set "ddf1_bar" was not activated
```

- 2.6.18's init script: http://fpaste.org/byZ3/
- 2.6.34.14's: http://fpaste.org/8COr/

They are mostly the same except that the following modules are not loaded into the newer kernel:

```
echo "Loading dm-mem-cache.ko module"
insmod /lib/dm-mem-cache.ko 
echo "Loading dm-message.ko module"
insmod /lib/dm-message.ko 
echo "Loading dm-raid45.ko module"
insmod /lib/dm-raid45.ko
```

Is this the reason for `RAID set "ddf1_foo" was not activated`?

---

**UPDATE Thu Apr  4 21:40:32 ICT 2013**

http://alistairphipps.com/wiki/index.php?title=Notes#LVM

> A strange error message similar to "mirror log: unrecognised sync
>   argument to mirror log: 2", "table: mirror: Error creating mirror
>   dirty log" means you have mismatched kernel device mapper and
>   userspace tools versions: probably your kernel is too recent for your
>   version of the lvm tools. Install the latest device mapper and lvm2
>   from sources, and it should work.

I've tried to compile the latest version of [LVM2](http://sourceware.org/lvm2/):

```
# /usr/sbin/lvm version
  LVM version:     2.02.98(2) (2012-10-15)
  Library version: 1.02.67-RHEL5 (2011-10-14)
  Driver version:  4.11.6
```

but nothing change.

---

**UPDATE Sat Apr  6 18:51:31 ICT 2013**

**/lib/modules/2.6.18-274.el5/kernel/drivers/md/**

```
|-- dm-crypt.ko
|-- dm-emc.ko
|-- dm-hp-sw.ko
|-- dm-log.ko
|-- dm-mem-cache.ko
|-- dm-message.ko
|-- dm-mirror.ko
|-- dm-mod.ko
|-- dm-multipath.ko
|-- dm-raid45.ko
|-- dm-rdac.ko
|-- dm-region_hash.ko
|-- dm-round-robin.ko
|-- dm-snapshot.ko
|-- dm-zero.ko
|-- faulty.ko
|-- linear.ko
|-- multipath.ko
|-- raid0.ko
|-- raid1.ko
|-- raid10.ko
|-- raid456.ko
`-- xor.ko
```

**/lib/modules/2.6.34.14/kernel/drivers/md/**

```
|-- dm-crypt.ko
|-- dm-log.ko
|-- dm-mirror.ko
|-- dm-mod.ko
|-- dm-multipath.ko
|-- dm-region-hash.ko
|-- dm-round-robin.ko
|-- dm-snapshot.ko
|-- dm-zero.ko
|-- faulty.ko
|-- linear.ko
|-- multipath.ko
|-- raid0.ko
|-- raid1.ko
|-- raid10.ko
|-- raid456.ko
`-- raid6_pq.ko
```

---

**UPDATE Wed Apr 10 11:22:54 ICT 2013**

Do a search in the source folder, I found this:

```
# grep -lr 'Error creating mirror dirty log' /usr/src/linux-2.6.34.14
/usr/src/linux-2.6.34.14/drivers/md/dm-raid1.c
```

**`dm-raid1.c`**:

```
static struct dm_dirty_log *create_dirty_log(struct dm_target *ti,
                         unsigned argc, char **argv,
                         unsigned *args_used)
{
    unsigned param_count;
    struct dm_dirty_log *dl;

    if (argc < 2) {
        ti->error = "Insufficient mirror log arguments";
        return NULL;
    }

    if (sscanf(argv[1], "%u", &param_count) != 1) {
        ti->error = "Invalid mirror log argument count";
        return NULL;
    }

    *args_used = 2 + param_count;

    if (argc < *args_used) {
        ti->error = "Insufficient mirror log arguments";
        return NULL;
    }

    dl = dm_dirty_log_create(argv[0], ti, mirror_flush, param_count,
                 argv + 2);
    if (!dl) {
        ti->error = "Error creating mirror dirty log";
        return NULL;
    }

    return dl;
}
```

**`dm-log.c`**:

```
struct dm_dirty_log *dm_dirty_log_create(const char *type_name,
            struct dm_target *ti,
            int (*flush_callback_fn)(struct dm_target *ti),
            unsigned int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct dm_dirty_log_type *type;
    struct dm_dirty_log *log;

    log = kmalloc(sizeof(*log), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!log)
        return NULL;

    type = get_type(type_name);
    if (!type) {
        kfree(log);
        return NULL;
    }

    log->flush_callback_fn = flush_callback_fn;
    log->type = type;
    if (type->ctr(log, ti, argc, argv)) {
        kfree(log);
        put_type(type);
        return NULL;
    }

    return log;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the modules are in `/lib/`? On my machine I found these modules in ``/lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/md/``

Comment: What do you mean by "these modules"? `dm-mem-cache.ko`, `dm-message.ko`, `dm-raid45.ko`? They don't exist in the newer kernel. See my updates.

Comment: Are you open to alternative methods to reach your original goal? I think you'll have a much easier time if you don't use CephFS. I recommend exporting a filesystem on an RBD with NFS.

Comment: @JeffStrunk: I'm using [this](http://ceph.com/w/index.php?title=Re-exporting_NFS&redirect=no) alternative method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all the help of my friend, the problem is solved.

On the first attempt, he commented out the line `ti->error = "Error creating mirror dirty log";` in the `dm-raid1.c`, and inserted some debugging lines into `dm-log.c` to determine what caused the above error:

```c
    log = kmalloc(sizeof(*log), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!log)
        ti->error = "kmalloc error";
        return NULL;

    type = get_type(type_name);
    if (!type) {
        kfree(log);
        ti->error = "get_type error";
        return NULL;
    }

    log->flush_callback_fn = flush_callback_fn;
    log->type = type;
    if (type->ctr(log, ti, argc, argv)) {
        kfree(log);
        put_type(type);
        ti->error = "ctr error";
        return NULL;
    }
```

then recompiled the kernel and we get:

[image]

On the second attempt, he want to get the value of `type_name`:

```c
if (type->ctr(log, ti, argc, argv)) {
    kfree(log);
    put_type(type);
    char* typeN = kmalloc(1000, GFP_KERNEL);
    char* pTypeN = typeN;
    char* ptype_name = type_name;
    while (*ptype_name != '\0') {
        *pTypeN = *ptype_name;
        ++pTypeN;
        ++ptype_name;
    }
    ti->error = typeN;
    return NULL;
}
```

[image]

Continue tracing to the `core_ctr` and the `create_log_context` by using the above method:

```c
static int create_log_context(struct dm_dirty_log *log, struct dm_target *ti,
                  unsigned int argc, char **argv,
                  struct dm_dev *dev)
{
    enum sync sync = DEFAULTSYNC;

    struct log_c *lc;
    uint32_t region_size;
    unsigned int region_count;
    size_t bitset_size, buf_size;
    int r;

    if (argc < 1 || argc > 2) {
        DMWARN("wrong number of arguments to dirty region log");
        ti->error = "argc < 1 or > 2";
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    if (argc > 1) {
        if (!strcmp(argv[1], "sync"))
            sync = FORCESYNC;
        else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "nosync"))
            sync = NOSYNC;
        else {
            DMWARN("unrecognised sync argument to "
                   "dirty region log: %s", argv[1]);
            ti->error = "unrecognised sync argument to";
            return -EINVAL;
        }
    }
```

[image]

```c
if (argc < 1 || argc > 2) {
    DMWARN("wrong number of arguments to dirty region log");
    char* argcStr = kmalloc(1000, GFP_KERNEL);
    char* pArgc = argcStr;
    unsigned int temp = argc;
    do {
        *pArgc = temp % 10;
        ++pArgc;
        temp = temp / 10;
    } while (temp > 0);
    *pArgc = ' ';
    ++pArgc;
    //copy argv;
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < argc; ++i) {
        char* pArgv = argv[i];
        while (*pArgv != '\0') {
            *pArgc = *pArgv;
            ++pArgc;
            ++pArgv;
        }
        *pArgc = ' ';
        ++pArgc;
    }
    *pArgc = '\0';
    ti->error = argcStr;
    return -EINVAL;
}
```

[image]

Notice that the ASCII code of the black heart symbol is... 3.

Don't know why the author is mixing up the `core_ctr` with the `disk_ctr`. The `type_name` is `core` but the number of arguments is 3, so he trim the last argument (`block_on_error`) by inserting the following into the `dm_dirty_log_create` struct:

```c
struct dm_dirty_log *dm_dirty_log_create(const char *type_name,
            struct dm_target *ti,
            int (*flush_callback_fn)(struct dm_target *ti),
            unsigned int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct dm_dirty_log_type *type;
    struct dm_dirty_log *log;

    log = kmalloc(sizeof(*log), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!log) {
        ti->error = "kmalloc error";
        return NULL;
    }

    char* core = "core";
    char* pCore = core;
    int is_core = 1;

    char* ptype_name = type_name;
    while (*ptype_name != '\0') {
        if (*pCore != *ptype_name) {
            is_core = 0;
        }
        ++pCore;
        ++ptype_name;
    }

    if (is_core && *pCore == *ptype_name && argc == 3) {
        --argc;
    }
    type = get_type(type_name);
```

Let's see what happens:

```
# uname -r
2.6.34.14

# dmraid -s
*** Group superset .ddf1_disks
--> Active Subset
name   : ddf1_VCBOOT
size   : 489971712
stride : 128
type   : mirror
status : ok
subsets: 0
devs   : 2
spares : 0

# modprobe ceph

# lsmod | grep ceph
ceph                  176676  0 

# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ddf1_VCBOOTp3
                      219G   17G  191G   8% /
/dev/mapper/ddf1_VCBOOTp1
                       99M   64M   30M  69% /boot
tmpfs                  48G   16M   48G   1% /dev/shm
192.168.2.13:6789,192.168.2.14:6789,192.168.2.15:6789:/
                       72T   28T   45T  39% /mnt/ceph
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a ddf format raid array in the first place?  You appear to be trying to activate it with `dmraid`, which hasn't seen any development for several years and is more or less depreciated.  `mdadm` is much better supported, and recent versions do support the ddf format, though it's native format is preferred.

Make sure you have loaded the dm-log module.

Comment: Have you ever migrated from fake RAID to software RAID?

Comment: @quanta, yes.  Backup, format, restore.

Answer (score 0):

According to Ceph bug [4286](http://tracker.ceph.com/issues/4286), FUSE needs at least kernel 2.6.24 for atomic_o_trunc. I found an [RPM for 2.6.25](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/17925155/dir/redhat_el_5com/kernel-2.6.25-128.1.6.el5.binp.x86_64.rpm.html). This kernel appears to be for an HPC cluster.

I think your above issue is due to the heavy modification that Red Hat does to their kernel releases. It makes trying newer kernels much more difficult depending on your hardware configuration and software requirement.